# Stack Separate Columns with Same Identifier R

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to merge columns with the same identifier and stack these on top of one another from the same dataframe. Also to then remove NA values as seen in the *Desired DataFrame* output?

### Current DataFrame

```
id    Col1   Col2   Col3   
1     A      NA     C   
1     NA     B      NA       
2     NA     B      NA  
2     A      NA     C 
3     A      NA     C
```

### Desired DataFrame

```
id    NewCol       
1     A    
1     B      
1     C   
2     A    
2     B
2     C
3     A
3     C
```

Answer (score 2):

Reshape from 'wide' to 'long' with `pivot_longer` while removing the `NA`s with `values_drop_na` and then do the `arrange` on all the columns

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = starts_with('Col'), values_to = 'NewCol', 
        names_to = NULL, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
     arrange(across(everything()))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
     id NewCol
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 A     
2     1 B     
3     1 C     
4     2 A     
5     2 B     
6     2 C     
7     3 A     
8     3 C
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Col1 = c("A", NA, 
NA, "A", "A"), Col2 = c(NA, "B", "B", NA, NA), Col3 = c("C", 
NA, NA, "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: That was fast! I was wondering if they have different column names for example?

Comment: @machine_apprentice then you may use `cols = -id`

Comment: or by there index I believe as well, going to try it now :D

Comment: @machine_apprentice you can also use `cols = 2:4`

Comment: @machine_apprentice with `pivot_longer`, the types should be the same or else have to change it to common type before applying the `pivot_longer` i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(across(2:4, ~ as.character(.)) %>% pivot_longer(..`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we could use `splitshakeshape` packackge:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  merged.stack(df, id.vars="id", 
             var.stubs="Col", sep = ".") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-.time_1)
```

```
   id Col
1:  1   A
2:  1   B
3:  1   C
4:  2   A
5:  2   B
6:  2   C
7:  3   A
8:  3   C
```